# Drawing literal string in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, character, string-literals

I have the string as below

```
"!\"#$%\"&'\\(%\\)"
```

I am rendering each character of this string individually and I get `'\\\'` before `'('`  or `')'`

But I don't want to get that `'\\\'` before `'('`.

I tried by replacing it or removing it, but it does not work
How to do it?

Code here:
`input.Replace('\\(', '(');`

Comment: do you know that if you add `@` before you string you don't need to escape all special caracter? Use the `@` like that `string myString = @"!\#/$%?&"`. Also why do you print those one by one? Could you show us the code where you print those?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not only the debugger window? Click on the loupe in the quick watch window.

Comment: Do you get this in Visual Studio or in your form? You beat me to it tim..

Comment: @im_a_noob, you still need to escape `"` even with the `@`

Comment: @Liam true... not sure how it work in that specific case

Comment: @im_a_noob @"double "" quotes" -> double " quotes . you just have to write "" inside the string to get a double quote

Comment: @FabioMarcolini ok good to know thank. If OP give feed back he might finish be getting helped... here all we can do is presuming thing

Answer (score 2):

Characters **`/`** and **`"`** are special characters in C#, so if you want to print them out you have to use escape sequences. Type **`\`** before every **`\`** and **`"`** like this:

Code example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string s = "! \\ \" # $ % \\ \" & ' \\ \\ ( % \\ \\ )";
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

In this console example you'll get each character each time you press enter. By the way, the spaces I added are important to print each character. If you remove the spaces characters will be printed out in pairs.

Hope this helped.